# Hyperlink in colab markdown that opens within colab editor?

Tags: python, markdown, google-colaboratory

There is a file in my Google Drive `/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Models.yaml`. When I write this file path in markdown in colab cell, it's clickable, and will open the file within the colab editor, and I can make and save changes in real-time. Like this:

[image]

This is fine. But writing this way:

`#@markdown - Edit /content/gdrive/MyDrive/INITIAL_MODELS.yaml file to make changes.`

looks messy to me. Is there any way to shorten it like `[this](/content/gdrive/MyDrive/INITIAL_MODELS.yaml)`:

So, it becomes:

`#@markdown - Edit this file to make changes`

For me, writing this way won't work. It will open in new tab, and will give `403` google error.

Need Help.